# Reading application data from a TLS connection in Python

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I have used PyOpenSSL to create a connection object, and I have managed to set up a connection with a library I am testing.

I am using the bio_read and bio_write methods as I am not using a socket to transmit the data.

I now want to pass encrypted application data to the connection object, and retrieve the unencrypted application data back from the connection object.

Here is a code snipet to demonstrate my problem:

```
# Prints "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
print(conn.state_string());

# I give the connection 37 bytes of data representing encrypted app data
conn.bio_write("\x17\x03\x01...")

# I ask the connection to receive the data written to the buffer
conn.recv(65536)
```

What do I do next with the connection object? I've tried conn.read, but although it exists it is [not documented](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/ssl.html), and conn.bio_read returns a WantReadError.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite remember what I was doing wrong as I am no longer at work, but `conn.recv(n)` returns the application data. I believe the reason `conn.read` exists but is undocumented is that the object wraps a socket object, and so this method is a method of the socket and not `OpenSSL.SSL.Connection`. This would also explain why I receive a `read is not a member of NoneType` when I call it.